# Wrong xml format: white space error

Tags: java, xml, inputstream

I apologize for asking the same question, but as per my research it seemed in different context. I know why the error is coming but I failed to eradicate it without looking and following some programming forums. My program goes as follows: I am pinging a url and opening input stream, then that stream is written into an xml file. After that I am using Xpath to extract some information that is further used for some computation. My code is as follows:

```
    URL u=new URL("url here");
    HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
    InputStream is=con.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream br=new BufferedInputStream(is);

    File f=new File("data.xml");
    if(f.exists())f.delete();
    f.createNewFile();
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    int count;
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
    while((count = br.read(data,0,1024)) != -1)
    {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    fout.close();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc=db.parse("data.xml");

    XPathFactory  factory=XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath=factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("//tr/text()");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```

when executing this code I get : **White spaces are required between publicId and systemId**.
Since I am directly writing to the file, where can this white space error possibly occur?

Comment: can you show us the content of `data.xml`?

Comment: uploaded it here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=71469882106124398976

Comment: as [burna](http://stackoverflow.com/users/517740/burna) said in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14069218/1749753). You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML file.

Comment: Okay thanks, I am working with JSoup now but can you please tell me the possible reason behind which this white space error has occurred, because I simply copied the whole page tags to the document. Did it happened while I was copying the file or due to the fact that I was treating an HTML file like and XML? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your previously written XML file is invalid, this is why you get an error parsing the file. The standard XML parsing frameworks accept only well-formed valid XML.

If you want to work with invalid, maybe unbalanced, HTML tag-soups, I recommend [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) as it can work with invalid XML.